# No LaunchImage xcode 7 GM / iOS 9

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, launchimage

I have tried all types changes I could do in my project but when I run my app on `simulator` , I was not able to get `LaunchImage` .
There is no problem in ios icons .

I have used `Assets.xcassets`. In `ios 8 / xcode 6.3` i was able to do that easily but then I converted my project for `xcode 7 (swift 2.0)` , from there I was unable to get `launchImage` .
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you run your app no image shows up on the launch screen?

Comment: no Launch Image comes on any device simulator / iOS device

Answer (score 0):

The way I would add launch images to an app, would be to add the image to the `Images.xcassets` folder. Then go to the `LaunchScreen.xib` file and add a `UIImageView` to the launch image view. Then select the image you want to use in the attributes inspector.

[image]

### Edit:

If you want to add images for all devices you can go to the `Images.xcassets` folder and click on the plus button at the bottom of the lis of images, and select 'New Launch Image`

[image]

Comment: I'm trying assets catalog for App Thinning any suggestions . How do you add launchImage to your projects ?

Comment: Is it a single image?

Comment: Or, is it just one image that you are using?

Comment: LaunchImage is for all iOS devices my app supports .

Comment: I re-worded my reply. Does it make any more sense?

Comment: I'm using one image that is compatible for all devices in asset catalog

Comment: Thanks buddy , I want a suggestion can i individually add image for all devices as i can early able to do ?

Comment: @SabhaySardana, I added some more information and a screen shot to my answer.

Comment: I have already done but still it is not coming i.e only icons are showing not the launchImage. Made some new projects and there too launchImage not coming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89926/discussion-between-sabhay-sardana-and-caleb-kleveter).